# Select rows with duplicate values on 1 column SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server, I have :

```
     DATE                Cookie
===============================
1   10/04/2018 11:00:00   123
2   10/04/2018 12:00:00   123
3   10/04/2018 13:00:00   321
4   10/04/2018 14:00:00   123
```

What I want :

```
    DATE                Cookie
================================
3   10/04/2018 13:00:00  321
```

I really need some help, thanks guys.

Comment: What's your dbms? SQL SERVER or mysql?

Comment: @D-Shih mine is SQL SERVER

Comment: What exactly is the question? Are you trying to retrieve a row from a table based on the Cookie field, the Date field, something else? Please be as clear as possible explaining what your problem is.

Comment: What logic to get your expected result? Get all rows that have no duplicated value on column `Cookie`?

Comment: @PhamX.Bach yes, that's exactly what i want, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
SELECT Cookie,
    MAX[DATE]
FROM table_name
GROUP BY Cookie
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Comment: thank you, yours seem shorten than Zaynul Abadin Tuhin's one. Very appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select * from tablename a
  where exists (select 1 from tablename b where a.Cookie=b.Cookie having count(b.Cookie)=1)
```

Comment: You have to use group by always with having  keyword.

Comment: The on clause should be a where clause - there is no join happening.

Answer (score 0):

So you just want the rows where Cookie has one entry. This can be done like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA AS A
WHERE Cookie IN ( SELECT Cookie, COUNT(*) 
                  FROM TableB AS B
                  GROUP BY Cookie
                  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 )
```

Comment: Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS. - you can drop the count(*) in the sub query select

Answer (score 0):

You could use `in` below way but `exists` more approprite which you will get in @fa06's solution

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM TableA AS A
WHERE Cookie IN ( SELECT Cookie
                  FROM TableA 
                  GROUP BY Cookie
                  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t1 WHERE t1.Cookie = t.Cookie AND t1.DATE <> t.DATE);
```

This would perform better, if suitable index is present on (`Cookie`, `DATE`).